# Cross-platform tools: development for iOS without Mac

Tags: android, ios

The task is: I have to develop a crossplatform game-like app for iOS and Android AND I do not have Mac environment right now. Yes, I understand that Mac is required for publishing, but this is okay. I just want to make sure that after development for Android there will be as little pain as possible porting it to iOS.

**One thing**: Web-based frameworks are not considered.

The framework should support well both platforms, be free (or at least cheap) and should have good performance and a big supporting community with a lot of information on the Internet.

I am choosing between:

- Unity (would be nice, but $1500 a year is too much and free it
  requires that splash screen, which I most likely can't have)
- Xamarin. Not free but I have the license. As I know this is mostly for
  conventional app development, not for games. How do I make games with
  Xamarin?
- Corona SDK
- I know about Kivy - the python framework. Not
  sure about community and popularity there.

What would you choose among these? What other options should I consider?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say "web-based frameworks"? Cordova can be classified as such, but you are considering it...

Comment: Sorry, I meant corona. I had very poor experience with Phonegap projects and don't want ever to do this again. So I am trying to avoid everything which is based on HTML+JS+CSS for mobile app development

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for the clarification.